# <f:view> beforePhase method called twice when page loads

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to capture url parameters when page is loaded. I am using the beforePhase attribute inside the  tag to call the backing bean method which handles the PhaseEvent. I am able to read the parameters but there seems to be some problem. The backing bean method is executed twice. First time I am getting all the url paramters but second time I am getting null.

This is the output in the console I get (The line "BeforePhase ONLOAD" is my SOP statement inside the method. As you can see the SOP is printed twice (below is the console output) -

---

*** <_checkTimestamp> Apache Trinidad is running with time-stamp checking enabled. This should not be used in a production environment. See the org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION property in WEB-INF/web.xml

beforePhase ONLOAD

<_isBeanValidationAvailable> A Bean Validation provider is not present, therefore bean validation is disabled

beforePhase ONLOAD***

---

I have to use these url parameters to bind it to the view object and retrieve the data for the page. But if the method is called twice like it has been called here then the second will cause some database error or ultimately i will not see any records on screen.

Is there a way to handle this ?

I actually followed the Approach 1 example seen on this page - http://jneelmani.blogspot.com/2013/01/adf-how-to-call-method-on-page-load.html. In this example, he shows how to avoid beforePhase being called multiple times, I have done that but still the method is called twice.

Any suggestions here will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you know ADF supports a mechanism already for bookmarkable pages & URL parameters?

http://myadfnotebook.blogspot.pt/2010/11/bookmarking-with-adf.html